# facebook session trouble

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have a facebook iframe facebook app. At the top of each page I run the authentication script from the php example included. For some reason however if I login to one facebook account, access my application, log out of facebook and into a new account when I visit the application I am still authenticated as the first user.

How come the session still exists? Why does the Facebook library not realise it is invalid?

please help.

Here is my authentication script that I include at the top of each page. It is almost identical to the example. The only change is that I have added a line to pass a GET parameter through the login url.

```
 $uid = null; //facebook user id

  require_once "facebook.php";

    // Create our Application instance.
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $conf['fb']['appid'],
      'secret' => $conf['fb']['secret'],
      'cookie' => true,
    ));



    if (is_numeric($_GET['user_id'])) {$user['id'] = $_GET['user_id']; $loginUrlParam = '?user_id='.$_GET['user_id'];}

    //Facebook Authentication part
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
            'canvas'    => 1,
            'fbconnect' => 0,
            'req_perms' => 'publish_stream',
            'next' => $conf['dir']['app_url'].$loginUrlParam
            )
    );

    $fbme = null;

    if ($session) {
        try {
            $uid      =   $facebook->getUser();
            $fbme     =   $facebook->api('/me');

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
            exit;
        }
    }


    print_r($fbme);
```

**Update:**

Just found something very weird. I am able to be logged into facebook in two browsers. I know in the past if I logged into one from one from one browser it would log me out of the other. Is there a problem with facebook atm?

Comment: can you post some code or url showing the code?

Comment: just a note. I have the latest version of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is actually a combination of issues

First of all, you have cookie support enabled on your instance of the `Facebook` class.  This triggers `Facebook::getSession()` to look for a session in the cookie if a session is not provided in `$_REQUEST`.

And, by the look of this code, since you're obtaining the session *prior* to knowing who the user is, the old session that's still in the cookie is picked up.

Remember, logging out of Facebook is going to do nothing to delete/remove session cookies on *your* domain.

You have several ways around this.  If you're going to keep cookie support enabled, then you'll need to make sure you properly reset that cookie when an un-identified user visits the application.  This is something you would have to do on a fresh load of the canvas page - not something that's included to every page of your app.

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $conf['fb']['appid'],
  'secret' => $conf['fb']['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

// Calling this w/no parameters will clear the session
$facebook->setSession();
```

You can also just turn cookie support off but then you'll need to manually maintain the session ID and facebook session data as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I know if an 'un-identified user' visits the application? The user id that $facebook gives me is the one of the 'first user'...

Comment: I just re read your answer you said 'First of all, you have cookie support enabled on your instance of the Facebook class. This triggers Facebook::getSession() to look for a session in the cookie if a session is not provided in $_REQUEST.' A session is provided in $_REQUEST though as I can see it is in the url of the iframe. So why did the facebook lib not detect it?

Comment: Depends.  Have you migrated to the `signed_request` parameter?

Comment: I am sorry for sounding like a complete n00b but what exactly do you mean by 'migrated to the signed_request'?

Comment: In the application configuration, under `Advanced >> Migrations`, the current 4th option is labeled **OAuth 2.0 for Canvas** which replaces the `session` parameter with a `signed_request` one instead.

Comment: Ok, I migrated to 'signed_request'. Strangely though regardless of the $_GET parameters in the url of the iframe is still showing the old users data

Comment: scrap that... that last thing did fix it... just took a little while to update I guess